# How can i customize the spring initializr to provide the same functionality as start spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nexus, spring-initializr

I am trying to build my own version of start.spring.io which can provide the starter files to user by fetching the dependency from my own nexus repository. Can someone show the sample application for the same.

https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Could you please add more details to the question? `start.spring.io` is all about generating the correct pom file based on user preferences. Not sure what do you mean by "starter files"

Comment: Actually, I wanted to create a similar system as of spring starter. Upon going through it's github profile, I came to know that we can host our own version of spring starter by editing their source code. That's where I need some help.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/) and, in particular, [in that section](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/#create-instance). If that doesn't help, please raise an issue with what's missing and we can take it from there.